# Closure not valid with Grails 2.5

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I had the following code working with grails 2.3, but a strange behavior is happening with grails 2.5, and closure content is not parsed (no error in console still). In example below, the println for debug purpose is not displayed, in spite the correct form filled.

```
def send = { DemoForm demoForm ->
        if (jcaptchaService.validateResponse("image", session.id, params.captchaResponse)) {
            if (demoForm.hasErrors()) {
                render(view: "display", model: [demoForm: demoForm])
            } else {
                println "------------------------****"
                sesMail {
                    to "xxx"
                    subject "subject"
                    html g.render(template: "emailBody", model: [demoForm: demoForm])
                }
                render(view: "thankYou", model: [demoForm: demoForm])
                return [demoForm: demoForm]
            }
        } else {
            flash.message = 'default.message.captcha'
            render(view: "display", model: [demoForm: demoForm])
        }
    }
}

class DemoForm {
    String firstname
    String name
    String company
    String phone
    String email
    String message

    static constraints = {
        company(null:false,blank: true)
        firstname(null:false,blank: false)
        name(null:false,blank: false)
        phone(null:true,blank: false)
        email(null:false,blank: false, email: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: By the closure you mean the parameter you pass into the `sesMail` method or the whole `else` block (starting with `println`)?

Comment: else {..}, at least should println "---" , sesMail is ok already (plugin aws).